# How to improve Text Classication Model with CNN and LSTM elements?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, text-classification

I have created a `neural network` to extract either aspects, sentiments or modifiers. You can find my code below. I get an F1-score of about 62% with it, but I don't know why it gives me such bad results. Do you have any suggestions on how to improve my model and the f1-score? It is currently including Glove 100d, tensorflow, keras, python 3.7.

```
model =  Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(vocab_size, 100, weights=[embedding_vectors], input_length=max_seq_length, 
trainable= False))

model.add(Conv1D(1000, 1, activation=LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1)))
model.add(Conv1D(200, 1, activation=LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(units=100, dropout = 0.5, recurrent_dropout = 0.5, 
return_sequences=True, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.000001))))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(512, activation=LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))))
model.add(Dense(n_tags, activation='softmax'))

opt = RMSprop(learning_rate=0.0008)
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=opt, metrics=["categorical_accuracy"])
model.summary()

# fit model on train data
model.fit(x_train, y_train,
  batch_size=32,
  epochs=10)
```

Answer (score 1):

A few questions:

- what do you mean with "awful training data"?
- In what language is your data?
- Where do the pretrained embeddings come from?

A few things to try (in no particular order and by no means exhaustive):

- Use transformers instead of LSTM, and even a pretrained one (eg BERT) if it is in the right language
- Increase the number of layers of your LSTM and/or the CNN
- Find embeddings of larger dimension (GloVE is typically 300-d)
- Add (multihead) self-attention to your LSTM
- Do early stopping with a validation set

Comment: I mean the quality of the dataset is bad because it was labeled manually by amateurs. The language is python 3.7 (i am using tensorflow and keras for it). The pretained embedding is a 100-dimensional GloVe Embedding. BERT would be a possibility, thanks for that. What do you mean by increase the number of layers? You mean I should add a second LSTM layer for example? I tried 300d-GloVe, which did not increase my f1. What exactly is multihead self-attention? I tried a simple attention layer after the LSTM layer but it did not improve anything. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: What *natural* language? (e.g. English, French, German, etc.)

Comment: Multihead attention: https://paperswithcode.com/method/multi-head-attention

Comment: Yes you can try to stack multiple LSTMs layers

Comment: Thanks again for your answers! It's in English (laptop reviews). I will try the other things you mentioned.